# Weak convergence of measures absolutely continuous with respect to another measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact set. Consider a sequence of (finite, positive) measures $\mu_n$ on $S$ that converge in the weak-$^*$ sense to $\mu$.That is, $\int_S f d \mu_n \to \int_S f d\mu$ $\forall$ $f \in C(S)$.  Suppose that $\vert \mu_n \vert \le M$ for some $M > 0$.

Suppose that all $\mu_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to another (finite, positive) measure $\lambda$. I want to claim that $\mu$ is also absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.

If not, then we have a set $A$ such that $\mu(A) \neq 0$ and $\lambda(A)= 0$. But then, we could define indicator functions $g:= \mathbb{1}_A$ and consider continuous functions, $f_n$, approximating $g$. We would want to claim that $\lim_n \lim_m \int_S f_m d \mu_n = \mu(A) > 0$, but, by changing the order of limits, each integral is $0$ on the left and, therefore, the limit is $0$. Of course, this changing the order of limits seems fishy, and so does the convergence of the limit mentioned above.

But, I would be quite surprised if the claim I have is false.

Comment: False. Take measures with support on [0.1/n] that is density function is 1 on [0,1/n] and zero otherwise. They are continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and converge weakly to Dirac's measure.

Comment: You are right! Thanks.